# I have a specific problems while entering date using sendKeys in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My date field accepts the value MM/DD/YYYY. Here, as soon as enter MM, it introduces / and then as I enter DD, it again introduces / and then I will enter YYYY. If I use selenium sendKeys, it is not entering properly as the application introduces / automatically. How to resolve this?

Comment: Welcome to SQA.  What do you mean by not entering properly?  Please add a little bit more clarity, and I'll change my answer if need be.

Comment: Are you including `/` as part of your sendKeys command?

Comment: Can you provide a example website which have siilar behavior

Answer (score 1):

If the application is adding the slashes automatically, I would just send MMDDYYYY.  If it's not, try sending 3 times.  The first, MM, then DD, and finally YYYY.  If you are then verifying, just build a string from those values that will add the slashes between the values.